# Why Std. Dev. total in Jmeter has value of '8596.41' while all transactions are showing '0.00'

Tags: jmeter

Why Std. Dev. total in Jmeter has the value of '8596.41' while all transactions are showing '0.00'?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The standard deviation for the individual sampler is 0.00 because there is only one request/data per sample. So there is no standard deviation for only one data.That's the reason all the data e.g Average, Min, Max is the same number "`4038`" for the first row.

Now in the 6th row, it calculates the `Total` value.The field Avg, Min, Max are for all the five requests. The average is calculated based upon above 5 data.Same also happened for the Standard Deviation column. The value of std.dev at the last row is the value calculated based upon the individual average value in the above five rows. The std. dev for five data `4038,10054, 12793, 26361,2002` is `8596.408939` which is ~ `8596.41`.

Please refer to this link for step-by-step calculations to work out the [Standard Deviation](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-deviation-calculator.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Now, i understand how the deviation is getting calculated.